# What is meaning about ch2.1.1 of two scoops of django 1.8?

Tags: python, django

The ch 2.1.1 title is `You Can't Examine an Exact Copy of Production Data Locally`

Its content is as follow:

> When your production database is different from your local development database, you can’t grab an exact copy of your production database to examine data locally.
>
> Sure, you can generate a SQL dump from production and import it into your local database, but that
> doesn’t mean that you have an exact copy after the export and import.

What is meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you are running [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) in production, and [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) in development. The Django ORM gives you the ability to write python code that works across the three databases (in most cases), but each database supports different features which make them slightly incompatible with each other (despite them all being RDBMS's and using SQL).

If you take a database dump from your production Postgres or MySQL database and try to execute it on sqlite, it may load all the data, but there will be many differences behind the scenes (column types, foreign keys, indexes, any non-standard extensions e.g. [JSON in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), how queries are planned and executed, encodings, collation, storage engines, etc.). Even different versions of the same database software can work differently.

For example, sqlite only has [five data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): `null`, `integer`, `real`, `text`, `blob`. Compare this to the dozens of types in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html) and [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype.html).

I don't have the book, but my guess is that they're saying: if you want to be completely sure that the code you're writing in development will work the same on production, then you should use the same database software in both environments.

Comment: @Stevev Kryskalla: I have the book and your explanation is exactly whats written in there. Paragraph 2 is called "2.1.2 Different Databases Have Different Field Types/Constraints".